# Java persistence, communications between db entities and other models

Tags: java, mysql, persistence, toplink

I'm using the TopLink persistence library with the MySQL db in my Java applications.

I've developed the class library which is used by several desktop applications, it contains some classes that are specific for my project. Classes are linked to each other, generally with one-to-many relationships.

I want to have DB Entity classes and Project-specific classes to be separate.

How should I develop the communications between this classes (inheritance, using or something?). How should the relationships between project-specific classes be developed when loading(or putting) them to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess since it's a desktop application, it's a UI based application. So MVC architecture is most suitable here. Also I guess you would have to use Java beans for asynchronous access to the model.

First define a model with all definition required.

let say

```
        class person
{
        public PropertyChangeSupport propertyChange = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

        private String firstName;
        private String middleName;
        private String lastName;
        private int gender;
        private Integer age;
        .
        .

        set Fname(String firstName)
        {
                      propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("firstName",this.firstName,this.firstName         = firstName);
        }
        .
        .
        .
        public void setPropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport propertyChange) {
                this.propertyChange = propertyChange;
        }


         public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChange() {
                return propertyChange;
         }

        public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChange.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }

}
```

Now we need a model provider, which would be a singleton pattern.

```
class PersonMOdelProvider
{

private static List<Person> lst ;
private static PersonMOdelProvider content;
private PersonMOdelProvider()
{
  // Get data from data base layer.
  lst = new ArrayList<Person>();
  //load the list from database
}

public static PersonModelProvider getInstance()
{
 if (content!=null) return content;
content = new PersonMOdelProvider();
return content;
}

.
.
.
set ... get methods for binding db with model. 

}
```

Now on the UI part you first need to get instance of model provider, and carry all further interaction through model provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I if i've understood you, i will have 3 classes for each entity - the DBEntity class (implements Serializable) that is generated by the NetBeans, the model class (that contains the business-logic and associations, stored in Class Library) and the ModelProvider class. This also means that I should create 2 classes (ModelProvider and DBEntity class) for each model in every desktop application?

Comment: Now that would be your skill, to design the classes. You are designing the bases classes correctly, then you would be sharing most of the code.

Comment: BTW you would need a separate model class for each model, but model provider could be common for a few set of models. Again depends upon your application and designing skills